# TFS 2010 RC does not run Visual Studio 2008 MSTest unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, tfs, mstest

Steps:

- Run the build including unit tests.

Expected result:

- the unit tests are executed and succeed.

Actual result:

- the unit tests are built by the build, but this is the result:

> 1 test run(s) completed - 0% average
>   pass rate (0% total pass rate)  0/4
>   test(s) passed, 0 failed, 4
>   inconclusive, View Test Results
>
> Other Errors and Warnings  1 error(s),
>   0 warning(s)  TF270015: 'MSTest.exe'
>   returned an unexpected exit code.
>   Expected '0'; actual '1'.

All the tests are enumerated (four), but the result for each test is "Not Executed".

Context:

- Team Foundation Server 2010 release candidate
- A build definition that runs projects using the Visual Studio 2008 project format and .NET 3.5 SP1. The unit tests run on a development machine, within Visual Studio.
- The unit tests project references
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Typical test class

```
[TestClass]
public class DemoTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DemoTestName()
    {
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Do your tests run correctly inside VS2010 via the test runner?

Comment: @mfloryan: The project/solution is not converted to VS2010.

Comment: Did you try running the build with increased verbosity? Is there more info in the test results? I'd start by running the test runner manually.

Comment: Update: I tested with MStest /testcontainer:my.dll. Result: tests run and pass with MStest from VS 2008 command prompt, tests fail with MStest from VS 2010 command prompt. How can I get the verbose information? Is there an easy way to force TFS 2010 to use the VS 2008 / .NET 3.5 MSTest.exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS Build 2010 will only run VS2010 unit test packages as the need to be written in .NET 4.0.

If you can upgrade your projects to VS2010 then this will solve your problem, otherwise you can edit the build workflow for your project to use the 2008 version of MSBuild if you are still using the 2008 client.

**The easyest option is just to use VS2010!**

Comment: MrHinsh, if you are stuck using the 2008 client, how do you "edit the build workflow" to force TFS 2010 to build with the 2008 version of MSBuild?

Thanks!

Comment: David, you need to open the Workflow xaml file in VS2010 and change the path to the version of MSBuild in the MSBuild Activity.

Comment: I am using VS 2010, but my projects are still running on .NET 3.5 SP 1 (which will not change before end of year). I am also getting the same error message: `(TF270015: 'MSTest.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.)`. Is this because I don't use .NET 4.0?

Comment: WOW, this just saved me from Friday night broken build hell. Thanks to both questioner and answerer :)